# How to use an action within reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, mqtt

So I am making a connection to a MQTT broker via Redux. I have three actions, one making the connection, another one checking for error and one receiving the message.
Only the first one gets triggered and the other 2 do not trigger. The connection is successful.

Here is my code:

**Actions**

```
  export  const mqttConnectionInit = (topic) => {
    return {
      type: 'INIT_CONNECTION',
      topic:topic
    }
  }
  
export const mqttConnectionState = (err = null) => {
    return {
      type: 'MQTT_CONNECTED',
      payload: err
    }
  }

export const processMessage = (data) => dispatch => {
    console.log('Receiving Message')
    return {
        type: 'MESSAGE_RECEIVED',
        payload: data   
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
   import { mqttConnectionState}  from './mqttActions'
import { processMessage}  from './mqttActions'

const initState = {
    client: null,
    err: null,
    message : 'message'
}
    


const createClient = (topic) => {
    const mqtt = require('mqtt') 
    const client = mqtt.connect('ws://localhost:9001');
   
    client.on('connect', function () {
      mqttConnectionState('MQTT_CONNECTED')
   
      client.subscribe(topic, (err, granted) => {
        if (err) alert(err)
        console.log(`Subscribed to: ` + topic)
        console.log(granted)
      });
    });

      //messages recevied during subscribe mode will be output here
      client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        // message is Buffer
        console.log(message.toString())
        processMessage({topic, message})
        //  client.end() will stop the constant flow of values
        })
   
    return client;
   }
   
   const mqttReducer =  (state = initState, action) =>{
     switch (action.type) {
       case 'INIT_CONNECTION':
         return {
           ...state,
           client: createClient(action.topic)
         }
       case 'MQTT_CONNECTED':
         return {
           ...state,
           err: action.payload
         }
        case 'MESSAGE_RECEIVED':
            return {
            ...state,
            message: action.payload //payload:data
         }
       default:
         return state
     }
   }

export default mqttReducer
```

Why mqttConnectionState and processMessage do not get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

**You can *never* call async logic from within a reducer!**  Your `createClient` method is entirely async logic, and so it cannot go in a reducer.

In addition, [you should not put non-serializable values into the Redux store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).

Instead, we recommend that [persistent connections like sockets should go into middleware](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live).